# How to degug a standalone Java program in Eclipse using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am a beginner with Java, Maven, and Eclipse.

I have made a simple standalone Java program and generated a Maven package with Eclipse LUNA. When I began to debug the Java program, I found that breakpoints did not work. When setting the breakpoint, there will be a circle at the beginning of code line.

Now there was circle, but it had a line over the circle.

How can I execute debugging the Java program with Maven in Eclipse?

Comment: Maven is a software lifecycle tool... it has nothing to do with your breakpoints. Perhaps you're trying to place a breakpoint on a line of code that will not actually be executed?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

a.Right click project.Then, Debug as -> Maven build ...

b.In the goals field put  **-Dmaven.surefire.debug test**

c.In the parameters put a new parameter called forkMode with a value of never

Set your breakpoints down and run this configuration and it should hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really saying "line over circle" then you have breakpoints there in eclipse and disabled.

Go to "Debug" view > Breakpoints and enable you should stop at your breakpoints then in your debug session